# Which of these forms is the correct one?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, subordinate-clauses

Which of these forms is the correct one?

> Addressing the students as a class, ask them who they think **the culprit is**.

> Addressing the students as a class, ask them who they think **is the culprit**.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that both are correct but they have slightly different meanings.

In order to see this, let's first consider this sentence:

> They think the culprit is John.

In this sentence, "the culprit" is a subject and "John" is a predicative nominal. We can turn this into a nominal clause by replacing "John" with "who" and fronting it:

> who they think the culprit is

Voila! We have generated the nominal clause of your first sentence.

Now let's consider another sentence:

> They think John is the culprit.

Now "John" is a subject and "the culprit" is a predicative nominal. We can again turn this into a nominal clause by replacing "John" with "who" and fronting it:

> who they think is the culprit

How about that! We have generated the nominal clause of your second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

Who **is** the culprit? (simple question)

Ask them who the culprit **is**. (Indirect question)

...ask them who they think **the culprit is**. (NOT 'is the culprit')

When a question (who *is* the culprit?) is part of a long sentence, the question loses its normal question word order.(who the culprit *is*)

Comment: Your second example sentence could be written as "ask them who is the culprit". Both forms are correct and widely used.